# How do I use multiline regex match in Jenkins / Groovy

Tags: regex, jenkins-groovy, multiline, changelog

In Jenkins I'm building a step that reads `CHANGELOG.md` and uses regex to extract the latest changelog from giving version.

The used `.groovy` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def String currentTag = '0.1.0';
def String changelogFileName = 'CHANGELOG.md';

def changelogText = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(changelogFileName)))
def pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)^## ${currentTag}.*?(?=\n\n## |\\z)", Pattern.MULTILINE)
def matcher = pattern.matcher(changelogText)

if (matcher.find()) {
    def latestChangelog = matcher.group()
    println latestChangelog.strip()
}
```

The used input file:

```
# Changelog - Project
All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.
This project adheres to [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).
Changelog based on guidelines from
[Keep a CHANGELOG](http://keepachangelog.com/).

## 0.3.0 - 2022-06-30
### Changed:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla
### Also Changed:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla

## 0.2.0 - 2022-06-09
### Added:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla

## 0.1.1 - 2022-06-08
### Fixed:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla

## 0.1.0 - 2022-06-08
### Added:
 - MDN-XXXX: blabla
 - MDN-XXXX: blabla
```

Locally this code works great.
However, I want to use it in Jenkins, and there it's a security issues to directly import these:

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.regex.Pattern
```

Hence, I need to change it to Jenkins friendly code.

So I changed it to this:

```
    def changelogText = readFile(file: changelogFileName)

    def pattern = "(?s)^## ${currentTag}.*?(?=\n\n## |\\z)"
    def matcher = (changelogText =~ pattern)

    if (matcher.find()) {
        def latestChangelog = matcher.group();
        println(latestChangelog.strip());
    } else {
        println('Could not parse latest changelog.');
    }
```

However, I keep getting 'Could not parse latest changelog.'

It's quite hard to debug when I have to run it on Jenkins the whole time.
Does anyone know how to make the Jenkins libraries available locally, or better, how I can match using `Pattern.MULTILINE`?

Or perhaps a suggestion for a whole different approach?

Comment: Use `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?`

Comment: thanks, but only doing that replacement doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Is this a Java regex engine ? Also, not a good idea to put control codes in your regex i.e. `"\n\n"`

Comment: Apache Groovy is a Java-syntax-compatible object-oriented programming language for the Java platform.

However, as this code is used in the CI/CD Jenkins, some libraries cannot be used due to security concerns. Hence Jenkins comes with some self maintained libraries that you can use. However, it seems that for regex the library is insufficient for the use case I use.At least, for the approach I took, Im not a pro in groovy nor regex. Hence I used awk for now.

Comment: Thre is always this one `"(?ms)^## ${currentTag}(?:(?!\\R##).)*"`

https://regex101.com/r/zmcrjK/1 Others too. Need to see a sample text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all symbols including newlines, you can use `[\s\S]`. This will work without any flags.

Consider the following demo:

```java
String changelogText = """
# Changelog - Project
All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.
This project adheres to [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).
Changelog based on guidelines from
[Keep a CHANGELOG](http://keepachangelog.com/).

## 0.3.0 - 2022-06-30
### Changed:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla
### Also Changed:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla

## 0.2.0 - 2022-06-09
### Added:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla

## 0.1.1 - 2022-06-08
### Fixed:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla

## 0.1.0 - 2022-06-08
### Added:
 - MDN-XXXX: blabla
 - MDN-XXXX: blabla
"""

def currentTag = "0.2.0 - 2022-06-09"
def pattern = /## ${currentTag}[\s\S]*?(?=\n\n## |\z)/
def matcher = (changelogText =~ pattern)

if (matcher.find()) {
    def latestChangelog = matcher[0];
    println(latestChangelog);
} else {
    println('Could not parse latest changelog.');
}
```

Output:

```
## 0.2.0 - 2022-06-09
### Added:
- MDN-XXXX: blabla
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is a very clear example which helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants to use `awk` instead, this in an `awk` solution, however, I still prefer the above one as it's better in case if the last entry `0.1.0` has some empty lines in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

/**
 * Get latest changelog data from given filename and tag
 * @param currentTag string
 * @param changelogFileName string
 */
def call(
    String currentTag = '0.1.0',
    String changelogFileName = 'CHANGELOG.md'
) {
    def changelogText  = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "awk '{ RS=\"\" } /## ${currentTag}.*?(^## |\$)/' ${changelogFileName}").strip();
    if (changelogText) {
        return changelogText;
    } else {
        return "Could not parse the changelog of tag ${currentTag} in ${changelogFileName}. Is changelog pushed? Or perhaps the changelog contains a syntax error?";
    }
}
```

Comment: agreed, removed it